# Documents in Word need to be saved in a 'Recent Place' first

Tags: ms-office

I have Word 2011 for Mac. When I want to save a document for the first time using Save As, in the 'Where' box I have 'Documents' showing. When I click the arrows to the right, I thought all Word folders would then appear but they don't—only 'Recent Place' appears. The only way I can get round this is to save the document in a 'Recent Place' then go into 'Finder' and move it into the correct Folder before I forget where I put it.

Answer (score 1):

If you click the disclosure triangle next to the filename, you'll see a Finder-like window. That will let navigate to any folder (or disk) that you want.

[image: Initial 'Save As' dialog in Word 2011]

[image: Expanded 'Save As' dialog in Word 2011]

Answer (score 0):

The arrows normally navigate between folders you've already visited.  Try clicking on the "Documents" folder in the left-most pane of the "Save..." or "Save As..." dialog box.  This should expose your Documents folder.

[image: Click here for a picture of the MS Word for Mac 2011 Save dialog box]

Also: play with the set of icons just to the right of the left and right arrows (triangles, really) just above the left-most pane of this dialog box.